# Meaning of "To meet a beautiful woman is one thing, but to meet your best friend in the most beautiful of women is something entirely apart."

Tags: meaning

> To meet a beautiful woman is one thing, but to meet your best friend in the most beautiful of women is something entirely apart.

I don't really get why this is considered so romantic. I feel like I am missing an important point here because English is not my first language.

Comment: The point is unrelated to language but to different cultural ideas of love and marriage. In many cultures in the West, couples meet on different levels, but not actual friendship ... because men are men and women are women. Still, to find a friend in your spouse is an ideal.

Comment: If a person you find physically attractive also turns out to be your soul mate, you are very fortunate.